# Windows 7 x64 Network Adapter Fails

Tags: windows-7, networking, 64-bit

Recently I have begun to experience problems with my network access using Windows 7.

The computer crashed after waking up from sleep and has not been able to access any network via ethernet since then.

The network is a simple modem -> switch -> computers setup that I know works because I'm typing this from another computer hooked up in the same way. The network adapter is a Realtek RTL8168B/8111B PCI-E GBabit Ethernet NIC that is built on to my GBabyte EP45-DS3L motherboard.

The Windows 7 box fails to get an address with DHCP and if the correct information is put in manually it still cannot ping the default gateway (192.168.1.1), saying that the host is unreachable.

Windows fails to repair/diagnose the connection issues.

Disable/Enabling or Uninstall/Reinstalling the network adapter in the device manager has no effect.

A system restore to a time before I had the problem had no effect.

Any insight into this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried downloading the network card drivers from Realtek and do a reinstall (not via device manager)?

Comment: That did it. How foolish of me not to have tried that already. 
I suppose I was foolish to have been confident in the drivers that Windows Update had procured. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: Some + rep would be nice too:)