# How can I determine what is killing my network adapter win7 or vista?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, networking, 64-bit, windows-update

I thought this issue was like another person [here](https://superuser.com/questions/41709/win7-x64-network-adapter-fail), and that downloading the nvidia chipset drivers was the solution. However that is not all that is going on.

This machine had Vista 64bit and is now Win7. Same issue with both.

I have explicitly been denying network driver updates since getting things working again and when a Windows updates occurs on seemingly benign Office updates the adapter fails to work.

Is the update process somehow protecting this machine by turning off things and it fails to recover connectivity after a restart?

All that seems to ever work is a system restore. Which does work.

Since there are 25 pending updates asking to do there thing, I hate to think this is a one by one update test to find the culprit.
Any ideas?

This has an integrated nic, video, and I guess audio on the motherboard.  ES5200 intel cpu on a gateway 4800-05e I am not quite sure how to determine the actual network adapter. This is a wired adapter. I suppose worst case I can try another adapter if this keeps happening.

Comment: Some details would help on the exact model of your network adapter.

Comment: This is an integrated nvidia nforce, and I have recently feedback where other people have had the same issue. I believe this may be related to the way power is cycled off by the udate. For instance a power failure achieves the same problem as a windows update. Where the hic does not re-initialize

Comment: Which nForce model, and what level is your video driver? What model exactly is your network card? Is the network wired or wireless? If Wireless then what model is the router? It would be easier if you gave full details to start with ...

Answer (score 0):

Are you updating via WiFi or hardwired? Any firewalls? Proxy?
What model is your card?
Have you tried to go to the Microsoft Update site and download them individually?

Comment: hardwired, as I mentioned. firewall and proxy are not the issues as it is directly related to windows updates. Connectivity is lost when update happens, everything downloads from anywhere prior. Yes I have tried some individual updates but eventually have the issue. Even if they are not network driver updates.